# How to run elevated script by just mouse click?

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script. The script contains commands, which require the elevated rights.

How can I execute this script from a batch file? After an execution of the script, I'd like it will stay in PowerShell (`-noexit`).

How can I run elevated commands of PowerShell from batch (*.bat) file?

Comment: This is a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not SO.

Comment: How can I distinguish whether the question is for the SuperUser or StockOver forum? They are both about programming, aren't they?

Comment: Just because a question involves some scripting doesn't automatically mean it's on-topic on SO. When the question boils down to "what command do I need to run to do X" chances are pretty good that it isn't. IMHO. YMMV.